# Get value from HTML textarea in Servlet

Tags: html, servlets

I'm trying to get a text from user. But i couldn't do it. It all the time returns null. My code is :

HTML :

```
<form action="gorev" method="post">
    <textarea id="gorev" rows="4" cols="50">

    </textarea>
    <input type="submit" value="ekle">
</form>
```

AND SERVLET :

```
String gorev = request.getParameter("gorev");
```

Comment: Show us what URL your browser sends to the application.

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
<textarea id="gorev" rows="4" cols="50">
```

with

```
<textarea name="gorev" id="gorev" rows="4" cols="50">
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need to read `request.getParameter("gorev");` from the request in your server, should have a form element (input,select,textarea,radio button, checkbox,etc) with `name = "gorev"`. `id`s are used on the client side (usually by javascript for DOM manipulation and css for styling.) They will be not send to the server unlike `name`

```
<textarea name="gorev" id="gorev" rows="4" cols="50">
</textarea>
```